# Mysql case based on the existence of a value in a set

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to achieve a `CASE` statement where the `WHEN` condition works like a `WHERE IN ()` ? Something like this is what I would want:

```
SELECT 
    product_id, 
    count(product_id) as productCount,
    CASE category_id 
        WHEN IN (1,2,3,4,5) THEN 1
        WHEN IN (6,7,8,9,10) THEN 2
        WHEN IN (11,12,13,14,15) THEN 3
    END as parent_id
FROM product
GROUP BY parent_id
```

Motivation behind: Trying to do what I need to do in one query rather than having to pull off subselects or PHP `FOR` loops.

I don't see anything in the documentation how this can possibly be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a

```
SELECT 
    product_id, 
    count(product_id) as productCount,
    CASE  
        WHEN category_id IN (1,2,3,4,5) THEN 1
        WHEN category_id IN (6,7,8,9,10) THEN 2
        WHEN category_id IN (11,12,13,14,15) THEN 3
    END as parent_id
FROM product
GROUP BY parent_id
```

See 2nd part in [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Comment: Sweet. I never knew there was an alternative syntax. Thanks.

Comment: @IntegralWind-up does the code you posted in question works fine ??

Comment: My question was missing an END so I edited it. Benni's answer is missing an END because he probably copied over my sql snippet. I already made a suggested edit for this answer. His answer is spot on.

Comment: @IntegralWind-up yeah i got it ..so my qus is that   the code provided in your question is working or not ??

Comment: The sql snippet in my question has a syntax error in between `WHEN` and `IN`.